# Angular animation: transition isn't working

Tags: angular, animation

I'm trying to make an animation, where a navigation bar slides in from the left side, when an image is clicked in the header. Everything seems to be working fine, when I click the image the navigation bar dissapears/appears, apart from the transition.

**content.component.html**

```
<app-nav [@slideMenu]="isVisible ? true : false" [hidden]="!isVisible"></app-nav>
<app-main></app-main>
```

**content.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('slideMenu', [
      state('false', style({
        transform: 'translateX(-350px)'
      })),
      state('true', style({
        transform: 'translateX(0)'
      })),
      transition('true <=> false', animate('500s ease-in-out'))
    ])
  ]
})
```

I expect the navigation bar to slide in during these 500 ms.

Comment: I've also tried to do it with keyframes. Doesn't work either.

Comment: I just noticed that I wrote 500s ease-in-out. Changed it to --> "500ms ease-in-out". Still not working.